# What is the use of .npmrc file

Tags: node.js

I am new to web developement and encountered the file called .npmrc. But I really cannot grasp the reason for using such file in a project. Please can anyone help me to understand the reason for using such file.

Answer (score 0):

Change Your npm Registry

```
npm config set registry "https://my-custom-registry.registry.nodesource.io/"
```

Change Where npm Installs Global Modules

```
mkdir ~/.global-modules
npm config set prefix "~/.global-modules"
```

More info here
https://nodesource.com/blog/configuring-your-npmrc-for-an-optimal-node-js-environment/